# MailKit dotnet core on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, mailkit, .net-core

Running a Kestrel server managed by systemd using www-data user. When trying to send an email using MailKit with TLS enabled I get the following error message:

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/var/www/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/crls' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied`

One solution possibly is to set a home directory for `www-data`, but that seems counter intuitive.

Comment: faced the same problem. Ran under root instead of www-data

Comment: Root seems dangerous in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The call stack indicates that the code (MailKit or one of its dependencies) is trying to build and access a certificate cache. 
You can manually create the directory and grant the necessary permissions. 
Don't modify /var top directory as that's crazy.

First, you need to recursively create the directory:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/crls
```

and give rights to www-data group 
(if this is the group that runs your service)

```
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/crls
```